# Create tiles for google custom street view panorama in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

i am working in a web application in php where i want to use google custom street view panorama ([Google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple)) with my local images. but i couldnt get any way to create tiles from the uploaded (by user) 360 image to work with the api.

i have tried this following script to create tiles, but the tiles are not correct and quality is too bad,

```
function tileCreator($fileName){
//Larger images can require more memory and time
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
ini_set('max_execution_time','300');
//For testing purposes, I manually entered the input file name and destination folder
$destinationDir = 'tiles/';
if (!file_exists($destinationDir)) {
    mkdir($destinationDir, 0777, true);
}
//create transform driver object
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileName);
$sizeArray = getimagesize($fileName);
//Set the Image dimensions
$imageWidth = $sizeArray[0];
$imageHeight = $sizeArray[1];
//See how many zoom levels are required for the width and height
$widthLog = ceil(log($imageWidth/256,2));
$heightLog = ceil(log($imageHeight/256,2));
//Find the maximum zoom by taking the higher of the width and height zoom levels
if ($heightLog > $widthLog)
{
    $maxZoom = $heightLog;
}
else
{
    $maxZoom = $widthLog;
}
//Go through each zoom level
for ($z =0 ; $z < $maxZoom ; $z++ )
{
    $currSize = 256 * pow(2,$z);
    for ($y = 0 ; $y * $currSize < $imageHeight ; $y++)
    {
    //if the current square on the original doesn't have the required height, we need to find the correct ratio to use or the image could be skewed
        if (($imageHeight - $y*$currSize) < $currSize)
        {
            $heightRatio = ($imageHeight-$y*$currSize)/$currSize;
        }
        else
        {
            $heightRatio = 1;
        }
    //if the current square on the original doesn't have the required width, we need to find the correct ratio to use or the image could be skewed
    for($x = 0 ; $x * $currSize < $imageWidth ; $x++)
        {
            if (($imageWidth-$x*$currSize) < $currSize)
            {
                $widthRatio = ($imageWidth-$x*$currSize)/$currSize;
            }
            else
            {
                $widthRatio = 1;
            }
        //create an image to put this tile in
        $dest = imagecreatetruecolor(256*$widthRatio,256*$heightRatio);
        //take the correct chunk from the original, and rescale it to fit in the tile
        $ret = imagecopyresized($dest, $im, 0, 0, $x*$currSize, $y*$currSize, 256*$widthRatio, 256*$heightRatio, $currSize*$widthRatio, $currSize*$heightRatio);
            //save this image as a jpg, named according to its location and zoom
            $folder = $destinationDir . ($maxZoom-$z) . '/' . $x . '/';
            if (!file_exists($folder)) {
                mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
            }
            imagejpeg($dest, $folder . $y . '.jpg', 75);
            imagedestroy($dest);
        }
    }
}
```

}

please help if anyone has any php script or library which can create tiles for custom street view panorama.

Thanks

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? & have you tried anything?

Comment: thanks for your response, i have edited my question with what i have tried

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can't test the above code. Incomplete. And what does "not correct" mean?

Comment: It may have something to do with that user uploaded panoramas are stored separately to ones uploaded by Google. User uploaded panoramas have different urls and are attached to the user who uploaded them.